# Как вывести из массива чередующиеся положительные и отрицательные числа?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-8

Условие:

> В данном ряде задач вам необходимо будет:
>
> - Определить закономерность, согласно которой формируется та или иная числовая последовательность.
> - Написать функцию, которая формирует первые N элементов данной последовательности в виде целочисленного массива и выводит элементы массива на экран.

[image: От A до D включительно получилось, застрял на варианте Е]

Написать надо на Java, заранее спасибо за помощь!

От A до D включительно получилось, застрял на варианте Е.

Comment: Во-первых, Не публикуйте данные/код скриншотами. Во-вторых, "До Е всё сделал" - код где?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу 1

Comment: Благодарю вас, буду в следующий раз более точно формировать вопрос для получения ответа :) Спасибо объективную критику и за замечания!

Answer (score 2):

Варианты с использованием Stream API:

- Смена знака `1, -1, 1, -1...` - `IntStream::iterate`:

```java
public static int[] alt1(int n) {
    return IntStream.iterate(1, i -> -1 * i).limit(n).toArray();
}
```

- Смена знака для чётных членов последовательности `1, -2, 3, -4...` - `IntStream::rangeClosed` + `IntStream::map`:

```java
public static int[] alt2(int n) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
            .map(i -> i * (i % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1)).toArray();
}
```

- Смена знака для чётных членов последовательности + возведение в квадрат: `1, -4, 9, -16...` - `IntStream::rangeClosed` + `IntStream::map`:

```java
public static int[] altSq(int n) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
            .map(i -> i * i * (i % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1)).toArray();
}
```

- Замена каждого второго члена последовательности нулём: `1, 0, 2, 0...` - `IntStream::rangeClosed` + `IntStream::map`:

```java
public static int[] altZ(int n) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
            .map(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : (i + 1) >> 1).toArray();
}
```

Тесты:

```java
System.out.println("e: " + Arrays.toString(alt1(10)));
System.out.println("f: " + Arrays.toString(alt2(10)));
System.out.println("g: " + Arrays.toString(altSq(10)));
System.out.println("h: " + Arrays.toString(altZ(10)));
```

```
e: [1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1]
f: [1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6, 7, -8, 9, -10]
g: [1, -4, 9, -16, 25, -36, 49, -64, 81, -100]
h: [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0]
```

Оставшиеся два задания расчёт факториала и последовательности Фибоначчи по определению рекуррентны, то есть используют состояние предыдущих вычислений, и поэтому строго говоря не должны вычисляться при помощи Stream API.

Однако такие вычисления возможны при помощи промежуточных переменных-массивов для накопления значений.

```java
public static int[] fact(int n) {
    int[] f = {1};
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).map(i -> f[0] *= i).toArray();
}

public static int[] fib(int n) {
    int[] f = {0, 0};
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
        .map(i -> {int x = f[0] + f[1]; f[0] = f[1]; return f[1] = x > 0 ? x : 1;})
        .toArray();
}
```

```java
System.out.println("i: " + Arrays.toString(fact(7)));
System.out.println("j: " + Arrays.toString(fib(10)));
```

```
i: [1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040]
j: [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```